# Navigation Visual studio 2013 and windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

I basically tried every method, i tried     this.frame.naviget and I tried     frame.naviget I also tried navigation service but didnt work.

This is the come in xaml:

```
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="Name" Margin="23,327,19,-329.667">
        <TextBlock x:Name="App_Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black"  Margin="39,16,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Poly Cream" Width="378"
                   FontSize="72" FontFamily="/Fonts/the unseen.ttf#the unseen"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Buttons" Margin="23,452,19,-651.667">
        <Button Content="Summary" x:Name="Summary" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="108,143,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="50" FontFamily="/Fonts/AgencyFB.ttf#AgencyFB" Click="Summary_Click"/>
        <Button  Content="New Order" x:Name="NewOrder" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="99,19,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="50" FontFamily="/Fonts/AgencyFB.ttf#AgencyFB" Click="NewOrder_Click" />
    </Grid>
```

And this is the code for the xamlcs:

```
private void NewOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));


    }
```

And this is the code for mainpage.g.cs:

```
namespace PhoneApp1 {


public partial class MainPage : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage {

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Grid LayoutRoot;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel TitlePanel;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Image Logo;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Grid Name;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock App_Name;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Grid Buttons;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Button Summary;

    internal System.Windows.Controls.Button NewOrder;

    private bool _contentLoaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// InitializeComponent
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
```

And finally the error list:

```
  Error 1   The best overloaded method match for      'System.Windows.Controls.Frame.Navigate(System.Uri)' has some invalid arguments

  Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Uri'   

   Warning  3   'PhoneApp1.MainPage.Name' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Name'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```